# Can I return a initialized struct on one line in ANSI C?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, return, ansi-c

I just wanna know if I can do something like that...

```c
typedef struct Result{
  int low, high, sum;
} Result;

Result test(){
  return {.low = 0, .high = 100, .sum = 150};
}
```

I know that is the wrong way, but can I do that or I need to create a local variable to receive the values and then return it?

Answer (score 42):

You can do so by using a *compound literal*:

```
Result test(void)
{
    return (Result) {.low = 0, .high = 100, .sum = 150};
}
```

`(){}` is the compound literal operator and compound literal is a feature introduced in c99.

Comment: This method results in ram being allocated, by the compiler, to hold a 'Result' struct, where the fields are initially copied to, then copied again to the callers' instance of the 'Result' struct.  Those two copies and the allocation of the Result struct are real RAM and CPU cycle wasters.

Comment: @user3629249: But these can be optimized and are ABI specific. On Linux/x86-64 a two-fields `struct` is often returned in two registers.

Comment: @user3629249: an optimizing compiler will fit the struct into a single register whenever possible (on x64, [whatever fits into 8 bytes](https://godbolt.org/z/SDW76d) gets written to a single register), and of course will [optimize the entire result completely if possible](https://godbolt.org/z/QWk7gz).

Comment: If using simple structs, you can avoid writing the fields' names: `return (Result){0, 100, 150};`.

Comment: So, is this technically a type cast, because of the parentheses? And by the way, THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Answer (score -5):

```
struct Result
{
    int low;
    int high;
    int sum;
};

then to create an instance of the struct

struct Result myResult;

Regarding your question...

prototype for the test function

void test( struct Result *myResult );

invoke the function by:

test( &myResult );

the test function:

void test( struct Result *argResult )
{
    argResult->low  = 0;
    argResult->high = 100;
    argResult->sum  = 150;
}
```

Comment: Typedef'ing structs is depreciated??? Also, `test( struct Result &myResult )` - since when did this become a way to "invoke a function" in C language?

Comment: Your right, I'll change the line to invoke the function

Comment: I could not find the original reference to typedef of struct being depreciated, so I removed that statement